# SQL Error When Run In Site

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that generates and runs an mysql update query.
When I run the generated code in phpMyAdmin I have no troubles, however when I try running it from my site I get an error.
What is odd is I am using the same format for several other update queries and they are working flawlessly.

MySQL Query:

```
UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Name` = 'IT Specialist' WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = 63;UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Company` = 'CSG' WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = 63;
```

Error:

```
Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Company` = 'CSG' WHERE `bio_position' at line 1
```

Code Used To Generate MySQL Query

```
function update($rank, $name, $company) {
    if (!empty($rank) && $rank !== $this->Pos_Rank) {
        $sql = "UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Rank` = " . $rank . " WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = " . $this->Pos_ID . ";";
    }
    if (!empty($name) && $name !== $this->Pos_Name) {
        $sql .= "UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Name` = '" . $name . "' WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = " . $this->Pos_ID . ";";
    }
    if (!empty($company) && $company !== $this->Pos_Company) {
        $sql .= "UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Company` = '" . $company . "' WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = " . $this->Pos_ID . ";";
    }
    echo "<br>" . $sql . "<br>";
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        $capc = new CAPC;
        $capc->query($sql);
        Bio_Position($this->Pos_ID);
    }
}
```

Updated Update Function From Answers That Works

```
function update($rank, $name, $company) {
    $capc = new CAPC;
    $sql = "UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET ";
    $go = 0;
    if (!empty($rank) && $rank !== $this->Pos_Rank) {
        $sql .= " `Pos_Rank` = " . $rank;
        $go++;
    }
    if (!empty($name) && $name !== $this->Pos_Name) {
        if($go > 0){
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $sql .= $comma . " `Pos_Name` = '" . $name . "'";
        $go++;
    }
    if (!empty($company) && $company !== $this->Pos_Company) {
        if($go > 0){
            $comma = ", ";
        }
        $sql .= $comma . " `Pos_Company` = '" . $company . "'";
        $go++;
    }
    $sql .= " WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = " . $this->Pos_ID . ";";

    if (!empty($sql) && $go > 0) {
        //echo $sql . "<br>";
        $capc = new CAPC;
        $capc->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this in your class http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` has the same condition, so why are you dividing this to three queries? You can do:

```
UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Rank` = " . $rank . ", `Pos_Name=` = " . $name . ", Pos_Company=" . $company . " WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = " . $this->Pos_ID;
```

EDIT: (according to comments)

```
function update($rank, $name, $company) {
       $new_rank = $this->Pos_Rank;
       $new_name = $this->Pos_Name;
       $new_company = $this->Pos_Company;

        if (!empty($rank)) {
            $new_rank = $rank;
        }
        if (!empty($name)) {
                $new_name = $name;
        }
        if (!empty($company)) {
                $new_company = $company;
        }

        $q = ...

}
```

Comment: Using 3 because not all fields will be updated all the time currently attempting to rewrite the function that generates the code to do this in one query.

Comment: @Talon06 in that case how about managing that logic in php? see my update example

Comment: I edited the question with my new working update function Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> When I run the generated code in phpMyAdmin I have no troubles
>
> UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Name` = 'IT Specialist' WHERE
>   `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = 63;
>
> UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` SET `Pos_Company` = 'CSG' WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = 63;

Although phpMyAdmin appears to execute multiple queries at one time (it's actually splitting them up for you on the backend), in your code you'll need to execute them singly or rewrite the SQL to update more than one column in a single statement, i.e., `UPDATE capc.bio_positions SET Pos_Name = 'IT Specialist', Pos_Company = 'CSG' WHERE bio_positions.Pos_ID = 63`.

If you're using mysqli you can also check out [mysqli::multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple queries in one "batch" is disallowed by at least some of the MySQL APIs, but PHPMyAdmin allows it.

Seeing that the query updates the same set of rows, you can rewrite it as a single query though, this will speed up the execution since the WHERE condition only has to be evaluated once;

```
UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` 
SET `Pos_Name` = 'IT Specialist', `Pos_Company` = 'CSG' 
WHERE `bio_positions`.`Pos_ID` = 63
```

Comment: K I will attempt to rewrite my code to use one query or separate the running of the queries.
I was attempting to use multiple queries because not all fields will be updated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this    

UPDATE `capc`.`bio_positions` 
    SET `Pos_Name` = 'IT Specialist' 
    WHERE `Pos_ID` = 63;
```